# Android protobuf - parse GUID from response with single GUID in it

Tags: android, web-services, protocol-buffers, guid, protobuf-net

We have .NET protobuf webservices, one of them returns a single GUID in response, like this:

```
return newItemGuid;
```

How to read this value from Android code? We receive a response of 20 bytes, and passing them to either `parseFrom(byte[])` or `parseFrom(InputStream)` doesn't work - returned value is empty `Guid`.

How to properly parse such response?

Here are bytes from response:

```
[10, 18, 9, 73, -7, 96, 69, -115, -33, 29, 68, 17, -107, -110, -92, 46, -100, -113, -10, -64]
```

And GUID should be: `4c6640a7-c955-4c34-b2d7-7b470cba4a9c`

Comment: Well, a guid is not 20 bytes; it is 16 bytes. Do you have an example of this 20 bytes that we can see? and ideally the guid that it represents? Is it possible, for example, that this is the ASCII of the base-64 encoding of the guid ? (hmmm.... no, that would be 24 bytes)

Comment: Protobuf adds some additional data that's why it isn't pure 16 bytes. What is strange is that its `parseFrom()` method doesn't properly consume passed value.

Comment: wow; I didn't even notice that this was a protobuf-net question! (which is very ironic); one moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I owe you an apology here; basically, the v1 version of protobuf-net used `Guid.ToByteArray`, which - if I had to give it a name - I would have to call "crazy-endian" - and it uses what is perhaps a bad design choice of layouts. To illustrate the "crazy-endian":

```
var guid = new Guid("00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF");
var msBlob = guid.ToByteArray();
var msHex = BitConverter.ToString(msBlob);
```

Obviously... `msHex` is the string:

```
33-22-11-00-55-44-77-66-88-99-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF
```

You should be able to see how each input / output byte maps in the above; I mean, who *wouldn't* choose that as the obvious choice of `Guid.ToByteArray`? Just... sigh.

OK, so... that's odd... but: this unusual order wasn't noticed when v1 chose to use `ToByteArray`. Although, IIRC it *was* noticed how odd it was when v2 needed to prove compatibility (v2 initially made the assumption that it was implemented in a "sane" way, and immediately failed all the tests).

Now, protobuf-net uses the layout defined in [bcl.proto](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Tools/bcl.proto), specifically:

```
message Guid {
  optional fixed64 lo = 1; // the first 8 bytes of the guid
  optional fixed64 hi = 2; // the second 8 bytes of the guid
}
```

So - a sub-message containing two fields, a `lo` and a `hi`. The field headers for field 1 fixed64 and field 2 fixed64 are `09` and `11` respectively, so we should expect:

```
09-33-22-11-00-55-44-77-66-11-88-99-AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF
```

which is... yeah, that's kinda sucky. A poor design choice. If I could go back and re-make that decision, I would have made it just a `bytes` of expected length 16, and I would have fixed the endianness. Well, hindsight is great. It is, however, hugely problematic to revert a poor decision that was made many years ago without impacting existing code.

So that's 18 bytes accounted for. The final 2 bytes are almost certainly a leading `0A-12`, which means "field 1, length delimited: 18 bytes".

So; you have options:

- decode as a `lo`/`hi` pair, and account for the crazy-endianness (for which I have nothing to offer but apologies)
- change the .NET code to advertise the value as a `byte[]` instead
- there's also a case to be made for a feature request to implement `Guid` in a **sane way** out of the box; I agree that the existing implementation is frankly: bad - it would have to be opt-in, though, to avoid regressions